# yii2 login always return false

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to implement login function with database using Yii 2.0. I have tried for 3 days but it still not working. What did i do wrong?

Here is my user and loginform class

**loginform.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);

        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use Yii;

use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\helpers\Security;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'usys.usex';
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['passwd', 'user_name'], 'required'],
            [['user_type_uid', 'user_status_uid', 'msisdn', 'passwd_strength', 'banned', 'created'], 'integer']
        ];
    }
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'usex_uid' => 'User id',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password'
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                return new static($user);

            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username) {
        $user = self::find()
                ->where(["user_uid" => $username])
                ->one();
        if (!count($user)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new static($user);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param  string  $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {

        return $this->password === $password;
    }
}
```

I try to trace validation function to validateAnswer but when i tried to print `$this->password` it doesn't have any value.
Anyone has a clue?

Comment: When in doubt look at the logs. Also, put some more logging in your code so you may follow the flow easier.

Comment: did you look at the logs? It is your code, go step by step and see the problem. I did not see any big problems besides usex_uid that should probably be user_uid

Comment: yes i solved it by validating password using $this->passwd === $password but now it only shows blank screen, why is that?

Comment: @JoanNatalie check error_log

Comment: Try  `public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
  return static::findOne(['user_uid' => $username]);
    }`